# Data Management API Autodesk Error en subida de archivo

Tags: c#

Código para la subida de un archivo rvt con la Api de Autodesk Data Management API.

Para los archivos pequeños no tengo problema en la subida, pero cuando quiero subir un archivo de 46 MG el programa rompe.

He utilizado curl en cmd para realizar éstas subidas, y  no he tenido ningún problema con el tamaño de los archivos,
Ahora que quiero automatizar la subida,con RestClient me da este error

He probado a cambiar/eliminar el parámetro "Content-Length" en la llamada, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Ayuda, Gracias.

```
public static string Upload(string accessToken, string bucketName, string fileName, byte[] fileData)
    {

        var client = new RestClient();    

        client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(baseApiUrl);    
        var request = new RestRequest();
                request.Resource"oss/{version}/buckets/{bucketname}/objects/{filename}";
        request.Method = Method.PUT;

        request.AddUrlSegment("version", "v1");
        request.AddUrlSegment("bucketname", bucketName);
        request.AddUrlSegment("filename", fileName);


        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "48033792");


        request.AddParameter("requestBody", fileData,ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        m_lastResponse = response;

        // Get the id = "urn:xxx" 
        string id = "";
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
            OssBucketsObjectsResponse bucketsObjectsResponse = deserial.Deserialize<OssBucketsObjectsResponse>(response);
            id = bucketsObjectsResponse.objects[0].id;
        }
        return id; // "urn:xxx" 
    }
```

Comment: Ésta es la página de SO en español. Has de hacer tu pregunta en español o será cerrada. Un saludo y bienvenida a SOes!

Comment: Disculpad el error, ya está traducido

Comment: @ClaraAriasDelRey, nosotros de Autodesk hacemos soporto en Stackoverlfow, pero solamente en Inglés. En este caso, no hay necesidad de utilizar Content-Length, pero es mejor utilizar ResumableUpload en archivos grandes (perdón, mi español no es tan bueno)

Comment: Gracias! @AugustoGoncalves